# How to detect a whether or not a web element is present when loading a webpage using CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I'm currently writing a C# program which browses the net using CefSharp. I would like to be able to check whether or not an element is present once the page is loaded.

I've tried doing it the "classic way", i.e. using an event listener and running some javascript code however it does not work for all elements. For some it does, for others it just ignores the fact that they are present on te webpage even though I can see that they are there. For those elements, even thoug the script was sucessfully executed (response.Success), the result is null (response.Result == null) and I dont know why.

```
            browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("function isPresent(){if(document.getElementById('my_elemen_ID') != null){return true;}}isPresent();").ContinueWith(x =>
            {
var response = x.Result;
                if (response.Success && (response.Result != null))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Element located.");
                 }
            });
```

I would expect to get the output "Element located" but nothing appears.

Comment: Make sure you've read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Comment: I've read it but I don't understand why this part applies to this problem. I don't have trouble knowing how much time to wait before accessing an element, I have trouble knowing whether a specific element is present on the page or not. @amaitland

Comment: One of the biggest problems people health JavaScript is attempting to execute it before the DOM is loaded. It's not clear you are executing your code at an appropriate time,  that's the problem with only posting a few lines of code out of context. For all I know that's exactly the problem here.